# How to create OR statements from a list in Nhibernate Criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to make a query that returns the rows that has proper name.

```
public static IList<Event> ListWeaponAndTriggerEvents(ISession session,
    List<string> weaponAndTriggerList)
{
    session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Event))
    foreach(string str in weaponAndTriggerList)
    {
        .Add(Expression.Eq("name", str)
    }
}
```

I know this code is wrong but I want to do something like this (the logic). Is it possible to do it with OR or Disjunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
Expression.In("name", weaponAndTriggerList.ToArray());
```